# Create PrincipalContext using windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, directoryservices

I'm creating a PrincipalContext object for retrieving a user's groups from our AD database (we use these then for authentication to various parts of the site).

This used to be done using forms authentication, so the code looked something like this

```
PrincipalContext pc =
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com", username, password);

UserPrincipal usp =
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Guid, user.Guid.ToString());

foreach (var group in usp.GetGroups())
{
    // Add group to collection
}
```

However, we recently switched to windows authentication, and I no longer have access to the user's password.

How can I search the AD database using the current user's credentials? I've tried using impersonation, but it throws an `An operations error occurred` error on the `FindByIdentity` line. If I forget about authentication all together I'm limited in the number of groups that are returned.

Comment: When you say current user, do you mean the user running the exe?

Comment: @Anon Sorry, I should have mentioned this is an asp.net intranet site. I mean the user browsing the web page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a method I use, You could change it to return a collection:

```
public static List<string> getGrps(string userName)          
{          
    List<string> grps = new List<string>();          

    try          
    {
        var currentUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
        RevertToSelf();             
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = currentUser.GetGroups();          
        IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);          
        foreach (var name in groupNames)          
        {          
            grps.Add(name.ToString());          
        }          
        return grps;          
    }          
    catch (Exception ex)          
    {          
        // Logging         
    }          
}
```

I assume you want the results IEnumerable, which is what I did here.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working for me, and is far easier than what I was trying to do.

Comment: This is wrong! UserPrincipal.Current does not give the user who is currently logged in using windows authentication but the thread user. To make the difference, use : `var httpUser = User.Identity.Name;` (Gets or sets security information for the current HTTP request.) and `var threadUser = Environment.UserName;` (Gets the user name of the person who is associated with the current thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Anon's answer works for what I asked, but I also wanted to be able to search for other user's groups. The best way I've found to do this is to run the asp.net program's app pool under a service account, and then use my original code.

To do this in IIS Manager 7.5, go to the Application Pools, right click on the one your app is running under -> Advanced Settings, and change the identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to a custom domain account.

Comment: Are you still including the username and password in your original code or are you using an overloaded constructor for PrincipalContext that doesn't take those fields anymore?